# tour.goTo(i) is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

Following is my reference Code :

I am using Bootstrap tour for my application.

**Requirement :**

- I am on first step when I click on next then it is checking the value of '#id2'.
  If id2 value is not blank then it should skip that step and move to 3rd step directly.

For this I am trying **tour.goTo(3)**.
But this is not working.
Any help?

```
tour.addSteps([
        {
            element:" #id1",
            title: "1",
            content: "1st Content.",
            placement: "top",
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('This is Onshow Function');
            },
            onNext: function () {       
                client_text = $('#id2').text();
                if(client_text != ''){
                    console.log('----------client code present----------');
                    tour.goTo(3)
                    //tour.next();
                    //tour.hideStep(2)
                    return false
                }
                else{
                    console.log('-------client code not present--------');
                }
            },
            onHidden:function () {      
                tour.hideStep(2)
                }
        },
        {
            element:" #id2",
            title: "2",
            content: "2nd Content",
            placement: "top",
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('second step');         
            }
        },
        {
            element:" #id3",
            title: "3",
            content: "3rd Content",
            placement: "top",           
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('third step');          
            }           
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: The **goTo( i )** accepts an index _i_ which is 0-based. Maybe you should be trying **goTo(2)** instead?

Comment: AVK : Ok yes working. But step 2 is still visible.

Comment: I have tried onHidden and onhide but still step 2 is visible

Comment: You are right. I've fiddled around with it and it seems that you should put the _goTo()_ logic on the step you want to skip. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/2b5ua/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add this jsfiddle as a answer so that I will mark it accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fiddled around with it and it seems that you should put the goTo() logic on the step you want to skip:

**HTML**

```
<div id="id1">One</div>
<div id="id2">Two</div>
<div id="id3">Three</div>
```

**JS**

```
var tour = new Tour();

tour.addSteps([
        {
            element:" #id1",
            title: "1",
            content: "1st Content.",
            placement: "top",
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('This is Onshow Function');
            },
        },
        {
            element:" #id2",
            title: "2",
            content: "2nd Content",
            placement: "top",
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('second step');         
            },
            onShown: function () {       
                client_text = $('#id2').text();
                if(client_text != ''){
                    console.log('----------client code present----------');
                    tour.goTo(2)    
                }
                else{
                    console.log('-------client code not present--------');
                }
            },
        },
        {
            element:" #id3",
            title: "3",
            content: "3rd Content",
            placement: "top",           
            onShow: function () {
                console.log('third step');          
            }           
        }
    ]);

tour.init();

tour.restart();
```

Comment: This is Fine for going to next step but I want to move previous step also. So trying for prev but it is not working (Question link is :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798461/tour-prev-or-onprev-if-i-am-skipping-step-using-onshown-for-moving-next)

Comment: how to skip steps using goTo() function