# Bootstrap tour won't pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tour

I am using [this](http://bootstraptour.com/api/) for reference.

In my code I have all input fields.

1. I want to do is, if that input field is empty, then user should not be
   able to move or goto next step.

I am searching desperately for this but not getting any documentation.

Any Suggestion or reference or example please?

Comment: Please include a working sample of your code that reproduces this issue with the least amount of code possible.

Comment: Do you have any existing code you can share? Probably put on jsfiddle as well.